# What is OBB(Opaque Binary Blob) in Android develop site?

Tags: android

When I checked the Android 2.3 doc, I found the information about OBB(Opaque Binary Blob) in Storage section.

But I can't find any information of OBB(Opaque Binary Blob) in Google.

Can you give me a information or address about what Obb(Opaque Binary Blob) is?

Comment: Read this documentation about OBB. [Opaque Binary Blob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_binary_blob) It provides details about general meaning of OBB and also what this term is used in Android.

Answer (score 29):

OBB lets you package up large files and store them on the public SDcard in a way that only your app can decrypt and use them. After building the AOSP the `mkobb`.sh and `obbtool` allow you to create (on Linux) OBB files.

After setting up things like PATH, permissions and kernel modules, creating is basicly:

```
$ mkobb.sh -d /data/myfiles -k my_secret_key -o /data/data.obb
$ obbtool a -n com.example.myapp -v 1 -s seed_from_mkobb /data/data.obb
```

After which you can store the data.obb on SDcard and only access the files from your app with use of the `my_secret_key`

```
storage = (StorageManager) getSystemService( STORAGE_SERVICE );
storage.mountObb( obbFilepath, "my_secret_key", myListener );
obbContentPath = storage.getMountedObbPath( obbFilepath );
```

Although other apps can destroy the data.obb on SD card only the app can access them and the content is as secure as if stored in app private.

Only on API level 9 and up and with the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to access OBB files from SD.

Comment: Which is the right way for unzipping or unpacking the expansion APK Expansion Files obb files to sdcard/Android/data (recommended because it removes when your application get uninstalled). I can use this goo.gl/OJfLk for unzipping? because I'm failed access the html files from obb file path.