# Where to safely put large data in android

Tags: android, internal

I have to store a lot of images that have to be downloaded from the web server. The size of the images might be 80Mb. So I want a guidance where to store them, whether in internal or external storage. Both create some problems for me. Internal storage is as every one knows is very limited but the problem with external storage is that images can be accessed by user. I don't wanna my application images to be exposed to user and changed or deleted. So is there any alternative or is there any technique to safely put data into external storage?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, external storage has FAT file system, which does not support access restriction. And you simply must not store such large chunks of data in internal memory (or otherwise users will not like you, to put it mildly).

So the only way to go, is to use external storage. If you need some protection, then you may either encrypt/decrypt data. Or just obfuscate data, like changing file extensions, or adding 10 bytes at the beginning of each file. Obfuscation is more efficient resource-wise, but much less protected. Though encryption key can still be extracted from your application, so both of this approaches have their flows.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to store them in the external storage. If you don't want the user to be able to read it, protect it with an encryption. I think it's a bad idea to impose large data to the user. If the user wants to remove it, you shouldn't want to prevent it. Perhaps consider the possibility of re-download the pictures from the web if it has been deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure but if you have any copyright, that doesn't affect the number of times you're allowed to download the files. Also, copyrights should be the same wether you copy your files on internal or external storage.

Answer (score 1):

Use encryption for file content:

i found nice and lightweight sample code on http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings

Answer (score 0):

I recommend saving to external. Preventing the user from deleting his data is not recommended. Also user can format the sdcard to delete it. so you cannot stop the user. You can hide it from him. Just prefix a dot to the folder name to make it hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android 2.3, OBB is your choice.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html

> OBBs contain a filesystem that maybe be encrypted on disk and mounted on-demand from an application. OBBs are a good way of providing large amounts of binary assets without packaging them into APKs as they may be multiple gigabytes in size. However, due to their size, they're most likely stored in a shared storage pool accessible from all programs. The system does not guarantee the security of the OBB file itself: if any program modifies the OBB, there is no guarantee that a read from that OBB will produce the expected output.

Related
[What is OBB(Opaque Binary Blob) in Android develop site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524981/what-is-obbopaque-binary-blob-in-android-develop-site)