# can mount unencrypted obb but with encrypted error 21

Tags: android, encryption, mount, apk-expansion-files

This is not related with kitkat bug, i'm testing in 4.4.2

I can mount without problems the obb file, the problem is when try to do the same with encrypted obb. I'm using jobb in windows like this:

```
jobb -d my_folder -o exp.obb -k pwd -pn com.example.name -pv 1
```

The only thing i changed to load encrypted obb file is this:

```
stgMgr.mountObb(mObbPath, null, new mOnObbStateChangeListener)
stgMgr.mountObb(mObbPath, pwd, new mOnObbStateChangeListener)
```

it's not a permissions problem. So, why i cant mount the encrypted obb file? 
i read this [Using encrypted OBB files in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101126/using-encrypted-obb-files-in-android) but don't understand the code. And is not in documentation. 
Thanks.

Comment: I experience the same problem, and I assume it's an Android bug. Since you are able to pass the password to the mount method as the second parameter, I would say it is intended to also work with encrypted files.

Comment: see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61881

Comment: A lot of people have this issue with older Androids and the default solution is not to use encrypted obb's. But that is not much of a solution. If you managed to solve it for encrypted, please share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to this bug for the time being. The only way to guarantee not to have problems with this issue in all android versions is not to use encryption encrypted obb files.