# Android save confidential file

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

Currently I am working on an app which has files stored in the `res/raw` folder.As I understood, these files are only readable but not writable?

My problem is that I need to change this files, when someone puts in a serial number, so that certain functionalists will be activated.

Also I do not really like to put the files as public on the SD card, since the users should not be able to get the content of these files.

How can I achieve this problem?

**First thought would be:**
The serial number and other settings information I am storing in the shared preferences... 
Also my question is, are the shared preferences accessible for the user, so that he can see, change those settings by himself?

If not then I could store the information to activate the functionalists in there.

Does anyone has some other suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure if it works but do check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524981/what-is-obbopaque-binary-blob-in-android-develop-site). If the phone is rooted the sharedpreferences can easily be accessed

Comment: if device is rooted then it is possible to read shared preference file... So Encrypt your info manually